# AWK: variables not remembered outside actions?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a script that will give the percent of logins that are mine. This is done by matching all users, store to variable, then match me only (jdoe). I then use a basic operation to get the percent of logins that are mine. I get the error:

`./loginPercent: line 13: eCount / totalCount: division by 0 (error token is "t")`

It seems that the variables in my awk code are not being "remembered" outside the awk's scope. How can I rewrite the script to make those variables global?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
last >> temp #Create a temp file that is filled with the last command output
awk 'BEGIN { totalCount=0;}
$1 ~ /[a-zA-Z0-9]/ {totalCount++; } #match anyone
END { print "Number of times anyone has logged in:",totalCount;}' temp

awk 'BEGIN { eCount=0;}
$1 ~ /jdoe/ {eCount++; } # match me
END { print "Number of times I have logged in:",eCount;}' temp

echo $eCount
echo $totalCount 
myPercent=$((eCount / totalCount)) 
echo $myPercent
rm temp #remove temp file so it doesn't change erroneously answers next time program is run
```

EDIT: It might be worth noting that I made a temporary file to store the results of "last" command to run the awk tests on.

Comment: The error is fairly explanatory... you have set `TotalCount=0`, and bash doesn't allow division by `0`...

Comment: @l'L'l, That's not the case as far as I can tell. The echos for eCount and totalCount both give non-zero numbers.

Comment: Try making `TotalCount=1`... then see what happens

Comment: I defined `$totalCount=1` just above `echo $eCount` and I get the same error

Comment: Awk is not shell. An awk script is not a shell script. Awk variables are not shell variables. You are as likely to be able to use the value of an awk variable in a shell script as you are the value of a C variable in a shell script. If you edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output we can help you do whatever you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: Ed is 100% correct, which leads me to question the comment :- "The echos for eCount and totalCount both give non-zero numbers" ... If this is true then the values must be set elsewhere in your code that you have not shown us.  Otherwise this is a fabrication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the output of awk to a variable, e.g:

```
foo=$(awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]/ { count++ ;} END { print count } '  file)
bar=$(awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]/ { count++ ;} END { print count } '  secondfile)
```

Use expr to calculate the variables:

```
expr $foo / $bar
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need multiple traversals or a temp file, it can all be done in one script

```
last | awk '$1 ~ /[a-zA-Z0-9]/ {totalCount++}
            $1=="jdoe"         {myCount++}
            END {print "Number of times anyone has logged in:",totalCount}' 
                 print "Number of times I have logged in:",myCount}
                 print "my percent:",totalCount?myCount/totalCount:0"}'
```

also, shouldn't totalCount be equal to the number of lines?  If so, you can replace it with NR in the END block and don't bother counting.